# Shift_A jumps further than the end_of_line in VIM

Tags: vim

I use vim to write C code. When I write something in the middle of a line and then try to jump to the end of this line using `Shift+A`, it sometimes jumps a bit further than I wanted.
Like this:[image]

I don't know what's wrong with my .vimrc.  Who can tell me how to deal with it?

Comment: Do you have trailing spaces?

Comment: Trailing spaces, `virtualedit`... you don't show what's in your vimrc: how do you think are we going to tell you what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

There is trailing whitespace in that line. This can sneak in especially with `:set virtualedit=all` in Vim, or by other (inferior :-) editors. You can make Vim show these with

```
:set list
```

(A handy toggle mapping can be created with `:set invlist list?`)

Because of such trouble, many people frown on trailing whitespace. There are plugins to show them as errors (e.g. my [ShowTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3966)), and others (like my [DeleteTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3967)) to remove those (even automatically on save). (The plugin pages have links to alternative plugins.)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do this to see if there are some unprintable characters:
`:set list`

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your vimrc, when you save your file and this will strip the whitespace at the end of each line.

```
autocmd BufWritePre * call RemoveTrailingWhitespace()
function! RemoveTrailingWhitespace()                                                                                                                       
     if &ft != "diff"
         let b:curcol = col(".")
        let b:curline = line(".")
        silent! %s/\s\+$//
         silent! %s/\(\s*\n\)\+\%$//
         call cursor(b:curline, b:curcol)
     endif
endfunction
```